# Google Dataflow StarterPipeline fails to execute in the cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am new to Google Cloud Platform, so might be asking simple questions

I was testing StarterPipline and Word Count examples using Cloud Dataflow API and although these work locally, both fail if I try to run these pipelines on the cloud dataflow service.

I've verified that all API required are enabled and I am successfully authenticated.

There are NO messages in LOG files and the only thing I see is that request staged class files on Cloud Storage and gives "Job finished with status FAILED" before starting worker pool (log below).

Any thoughts and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Vladimir

```
Sep 15, 2015 4:13:09 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner fromOptions
INFO: PipelineOptions.filesToStage was not specified. Defaulting to files from the classpath: will stage 45 files. Enable logging at DEBUG level to see which files will be staged.
Sep 15, 2015 4:13:09 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline applyInternal
WARNING: Transform AnonymousParDo2 does not have a stable unique name. This will prevent updating of pipelines.
Sep 15, 2015 4:13:09 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner run
INFO: Executing pipeline on the Dataflow Service, which will have billing implications related to Google Compute Engine usage and other Google Cloud Services.
Sep 15, 2015 4:13:09 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElements
INFO: Uploading 45 files from PipelineOptions.filesToStage to staging location to prepare for execution.
Sep 15, 2015 4:13:19 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElements
INFO: Uploading PipelineOptions.filesToStage complete: 0 files newly uploaded, 45 files cached
Dataflow SDK version: 1.0.0
Sep 15, 2015 4:13:20 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner run
INFO: To access the Dataflow monitoring console, please navigate to https://console.developers.google.com/project/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/dataflow/job/2015-09-15_07_13_20-12403932015881940310
Submitted job: 2015-09-15_07_13_20-12403932015881940310
Sep 15, 2015 4:13:20 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner run
INFO: To cancel the job using the 'gcloud' tool, run:
> gcloud alpha dataflow jobs --project=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX cancel 2015-09-15_07_13_20-12403932015881940310
Sep 15, 2015 4:13:27 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner run
INFO: Job finished with status FAILED
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowJobExecutionException: Job 2015-09-15_07_13_20-12403932015881940310 failed with status FAILED
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:155)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:56)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:176)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.starter.StarterPipeline.main(StarterPipeline.java:68)
```

Comment: Ended up dropping and recreating the project which solved the issue

Comment: Hi Vladimir, do you mean you've recreated a local eclipse project or a new App Engine project? I'm having the same issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sdk/Y-lkb2Q2fVU

Comment: Is this issue still happening?